# Why doesn't printing from Windows XP to 12.04 using Samba work? 

Tags: 12.04, printing, samba, windows-xp

I have set up my printer to print from Windows XP to Ubuntu 12.04. The printer is connected to the computer with Windows XP, and is being shared across my home network. The computer with Ubuntu 12.04 is connecting using samba. When I try to print it fails to connect to the printer. I get the error:

`Connection Failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't set you auth user and password very well. 
I also had that problem and solution was to enter syntax: username@domain instead of domain\username.

Also you can check on this page, there is solution for allmost all printer problems:http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html 
Here is link how to map drive , but you can use that concept for printers:
http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/map-network-drive-in-linux.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Its important that you explain your affliation with this link - if its your blog then say so.

Comment: @linomans I am tiring to connect to a printer connected to my Windows computer from Ubuntu. Not From my Ubuntu computer to my Windows computer. Sorry for not being clear in the above.